# Замена "маячков" в строке из файла на данные

Tags: php, html

Я как-то видел очень хорошее решение с помощью одной функции, но не могу вспомнить какой именно. Суть в чем:

У меня есть php-файл с кодом html. Там, грубо говоря, сверстанный блок с элементами. Я получаю этот html в переменную через `file_get_contents`. Оттуда и дальше его отправляю в обработчик. Но мне нужно перед отправкой подставить туда в нужные места данные.

Как решение - расставить в шаблоне "маячки", типа [email] , [date] , [name] и просто через `str_replace` делать замену. Но для этого потребуется запускать функцию, к примеру, раз 10 для каждого "маячка".

Есть какое-то более элегантное решение?

Comment: `str_replace` может принимать и массивы для замены нескольких "маячков" на соответствующие значения. См. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: уже есть ответ на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869964/replacing-string-within-php-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ваше решение: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php

Пример:

```
$replace_pairs = array(
    '[name]'    => 'John Doe',
    '[email]'   => 'some@email.com',
    '[date]'    => date(DATE_W3C, time()),
);
$string = strtr($string, $replace_pairs);
```